# Можно ли в Windows программно изменить вывод звука на наушники?

Tags: windows, winapi, аудио, windows-10

Сейчас звук воспроизводится через встроенные в ноутбук динамики. Необходимо программно изменить вывод звука на наушники.

Есть ли для этого функции в `Windows API` или может есть библиотеки, которые позволят это сделать?

Comment: Переключение происходит на уровне звуковой карты

Comment: Ну в Windows 10 можно переключить вывод на наушники/динамики.... Думаю в API чо-нить должно быть

Comment: Правило программиста №0: Научитесь гуглить по-английски

https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=windows+api+change+output+sound